# Qt application crashes after call to removeItem() in QGrahicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene

I'm facing a problem I cannot explain yet. In the "Designer" GUI there is a QGraphicsView which I use as a placeholder for a custom GraphicsView. I have overridden the resizeEvent() method there and set the scene's rect.
The scene which is a custom class, too I'd like to use to display a graph.

The problem: Sometimes when starting the application it crashes and sometimes it doesn't. This behavior does not follow a rule, i.e. sometimes I start it ten times before crashing sometimes three times and so on.

I took a screenshot of the call stack but seems like I am not capable of understanding the problem. Hope someone of you does.

First things first, here is the code:

mainwindow.cpp

```
graph = new GraphScene(this);
ui->gv_graph->setScene(graph);
graph->addAxisLabels("P", "t");
```

graphicsview.cpp

```
GraphicsView::GraphicsView(QWidget *parent)
    :QGraphicsView(parent)
{
}

void GraphicsView::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    if(GraphScene *s = dynamic_cast<GraphScene*>(scene()))
        s->updateSceneRect(QRectF(QPointF(0,0), event->size()));
}
```

graphscene.cpp

```
const float GraphScene::margin = 20.0f;

GraphScene::GraphScene(QObject *parent)
    :QGraphicsScene(parent)
{
}

void GraphScene::updateSceneRect(const QRectF &rect)
{
    setSceneRect(rect);

    if(_frameRect)
        removeItem(_frameRect);

    _frameRect = new QGraphicsRectItem;
    _frame.setTopLeft(QPointF(margin, margin));
    _frame.setWidth(rect.width()-2*margin);
    _frame.setHeight(rect.height()-2*margin);
    _frameRect->setRect(_frame);

    addItem(_frameRect);
}

void GraphScene::addAxisLabels(const QString& xLabel, const QString&   yLabel)
{
    if(_xLabel)
        removeItem(_xLabel);
    if(_yLabel)
        removeItem(_yLabel);

    _xLabel = new QGraphicsSimpleTextItem(xLabel);
    _xLabel->setX(margin+1);
    _xLabel->setY(margin+1);
    addItem(_xLabel);

   //_yLabel = new QGraphicsSimpleTextItem;
}
```

So as what I see from the call stack the problem occurs when calling removeItem() in one of the both functions above.

The screenshot:
[image]

Environment information:
[image]

Can someone provide some help, hints or whatever. This would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It seems that `_frameRect` is a pointer and you forgot to set it to 0 in constructor, so it has random value at startup. Always set initial values of raw pointers.

Comment: Ah stupid me, I simply forgot it. I even saw after my post that it had a random value. But simply did not see. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Note that the information from Qt Creator's About dialog does not necessarily apply to the version of Qt that you're using to build and run your project.